# How to call method inside class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I call `setStatus` from within `awakeFromNib`?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    setStatus; // how?
}

/* Function for setting window status */
- (void)setStatus {
    [statusField setStringValue:@"Idle"];
}
```

Comment: In Objective-C, you don't call a method, you send a message to an object. In your case, the object is `self`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Objective-C, you use `self` to refer to the current object:

```
[self setStatus];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you might want to revise that method to be this:

```
- ( void ) setStatus: ( NSString *) status {

    [ statusField setStringValue: status ];

}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
[ self setStatus: @"Idle" ];
```